# Issue in adding paragraphs to pdf usimg itextsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext, paragraphs

I have the following code whose output in a pdf file is:

> **Form M.T.R. 17**
>
> **PAY-BILL OF GAZETTED OFFICER**
>
> ```
>                                 DDO Code: 703
> ```

The code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
public partial class new_salary : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

        // Create PDF document
        Document pdfDocument = new Document(PageSize.A4, 70, 45, 40, 25);

        PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDocument, new FileStream("d://JudgeSalary.pdf", FileMode.Create));

        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDocument, HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);

        pdfDocument.Open();

        Chunk boo = new Chunk("Form M.T.R. 17");


        Paragraph main1 = new Paragraph("Form M.T.R. 17 \nPAY-BILL OF GAZETTED OFFICER");
        main1.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        main1.Font.SetStyle(Font.BOLD);

        Paragraph main1a = new Paragraph("          DDO Code: 703");
        main1a.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;





        pdfDocument.Add(main1);
        pdfDocument.Add(main1a);

        pdfDocument.Close();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
}
```

I want the output to be:

```
               **Form M.T.R. 17**

               **PAY-BILL OF GAZETTED OFFICER**                           DDO Code: 703
```

How can i get the above mentioned output with 'DDO Code: 703' in the 2nd line of the paragraph and no text formatting . If i include 'DDO Code: 703'   in 'para1' than the text is displayed as bold. **I want this output to be center alignment** accept 'DDO Code: 703' which i want to be right aligned.

I dont want it to appear bold and also want it in the 2nd line of the paragraph. how can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using iTextSharp, you can add text with a `Chunk`, `Phrase`, or `Paragraph`.  See a reference of how these work **[here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/82/iTextSharp-Adding-Text-with-Chunks-Phrases-and-Paragraphs)**. Essentially, you will want to put your paragraph together as a few phrases or chunks to allow for the differing font styles.

To achieve the positioning you want, a `PdfPTable` with appropriately aligned `PdfPCell` elements may work best.  Something like the following:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Form M.T.R. 17", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 12, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD)));
cell.Colspan = 2;
cell.Border = 0;
cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT; 
table.AddCell(cell);
table.AddCell(new Phrase("PAY-BILL OF GAZETTED OFFICER"));

PdfPCell rCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("DDO Code: 703", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 12)));
rCell.Border = 0;
rCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT; 
table.AddCell(rCell);
pdfDocument.Add(table);
```

Comment: I want the output to be center aligned. Can i align chunks,phrases?

Comment: If you look at the example regarding `Paragraph`, they show how a `Chunk` can be added to a `Phrase` which in turn can be added to a `Paragraph`. You can then call the `setAlignment()` function on the paragraph to center it.

Comment: Ya true,but i want 'DDO Code: 703' to be right aligned and no formatting to be applied to it.

Comment: You have a couple options for this. One would be to use a `Chunk` for the 'DDO Code: 703' and position it as needed.  An alternative would be to use a `PdfPTable` with a couple `PdfPCell`s having different horizontal alignment. See an example of using these classes here: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/86/iTextSharp-Introducing-Tables

Comment: Can any one help me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20950236/how-to-insert-html-markup-using-itextsharp-for-creating-pdf-using-c

Answer (score 0):

A paragraph will be in a new line, try to use Phrase like this:

```
Phrase main1 = new Phrase("Form M.T.R. 17 \nPAY-BILL OF GAZETTED OFFICER");
main1.Font.SetStyle(Font.BOLD);

Phrase main1a = new Paragraph(" DDO Code: 703");

pdfDocument.Add(main1);
pdfDocument.Add(main1a);
```

Comment: Can any one help me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20950236/how-to-insert-html-markup-using-itextsharp-for-creating-pdf-using-c