# How to Insert HTML markup using iTextSharp for creating PDF using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf-generation, itext

I am new to `iTextSharp API` to create `PDF`. I want to `Create` the a `PDF` similar shown in following image:
[image: Packing Slip]
I have added Table(`PdfPTable`) to Display the Left part (Text other than the Orange Bordered)

```
protected void CreatePDF()
{
    //Create PDF slip
    PdfPTable pdfTabdevices = new PdfPTable(2);
    DataTable dt = Session["MyList"] as DataTable;
    pdfTabdevices = GetDataFromSQLTable(dt);//Get the device lists
    Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 20, 20, 42,35);//iTextSharp.text.PageSize.Letter, 10, 10, 42,35
    int orderid = Session["OrderID"] != null ? Convert.ToInt32(Session["OrderID"]) : 0;

    try
    {
        string pdfFilePath = Server.MapPath(".") + "/pdfdocs/" + orderid + ".pdf";

        //Create Document class object and set its size to letter and give space left, right, Top, Bottom Margin
        PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(pdfFilePath, FileMode.Create));

        doc.Open();//Open Document to write

        Font font8 = FontFactory.GetFont("ARIAL", 7);
        string imageFilePath = Server.MapPath(".") + "/images/Logo.png";
        iTextSharp.text.Image jpg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageFilePath);
        //Resize image depend upon your need
        jpg.ScaleToFit(100f, 50f);//jpg.ScaleToFit(280f, 260f);
        //Give space before image
        jpg.SpacingBefore = 30f;
        //Give some space after the image
        jpg.SpacingAfter = 1f;
        jpg.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
        doc.Add(jpg);

        Phrase titl = new Phrase("\n\nPacking Slip\n");
        titl.Font.SetStyle(Font.BOLD);
        doc.Add(titl);

        Phrase titlDesc = new Phrase("Place this slip inside the box with your device");
        // titlDesc.Font.SetStyle(Font.BOLD);
        doc.Add(titlDesc);
        doc.Add(pdfTabdevices);

        string expdate = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.Date);
        Phrase expir = new Phrase("You have until " + expdate + " to ship your device.");
        // titlDesc.Font.SetStyle(Font.BOLD);
        doc.Add(expir);

        Phrase note = new Phrase("\n\nIf you send your device after the expiration date we cannot honor your initial offer. We will not accept devices that have been reported lost or stolen.");
        doc.Add(note);
    }
    catch (DocumentException docEx)
    {
        //handle pdf document exception if any
    }
    catch (IOException ioEx)
    {
        // handle IO exception
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // ahndle other exception if occurs
    }
    finally
    {
        //Close document and writer
        doc.Close();
    }
}

protected PdfPTable GetDataFromSQLTable(DataTable dt)
{
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
    //actual width of table in points
    table.TotalWidth = 500f;//216f;
    //fix the absolute width of the table
    table.LockedWidth = true;

    //relative col widths in proportions -  2/3 & 1/3 
    float[] widths = new float[] { 2f, 1f };
    table.SetWidths(widths);
    table.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
    //leave a gap before and after the table
    table.SpacingBefore = 20f;
    table.SpacingAfter = 20f;

    //PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("ITEM"));
    PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("ITEM", new Font(Font.HELVETICA, 10f, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)));
    cell2.Border = Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER;
    cell2.BorderColor=Color.WHITE;

    table.AddCell(cell2);

    //PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("OFFER"));
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("OFFER", new Font(Font.HELVETICA, 10f, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)));
    cell2.Border = Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER;
    cell.BorderColor = Color.WHITE;
    //cell.Colspan = 2;
    //cell.Border = 0;
    //cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1;//0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
    table.AddCell(cell);


    DataTable dtmain = new DataTable();
    dtmain = dt;
    double boxTotal = 0.00;
    if (dtmain.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dtmain.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            PdfPCell rcol1 =new PdfPCell(new Phrase(dtmain.Rows[i]["DeviceName"].ToString(), new Font(Font.HELVETICA, 10f, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
            rcol1.BorderColor = Color.WHITE;
            table.AddCell(rcol1);

            //table.AddCell(dtmain.Rows[i]["DeviceName"].ToString());

            PdfPCell rcol2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("$" + dtmain.Rows[i]["Price"].ToString(), new Font(Font.HELVETICA, 10f, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
            rcol2.BorderColor = Color.WHITE;
            table.AddCell(rcol2);

            //table.AddCell("$" +dtmain.Rows[i]["Price"].ToString());
            boxTotal+= Convert.ToDouble(dtmain.Rows[i]["Price"]);
        }
    }

    PdfPCell rcolSecLast1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------", new Font(Font.HELVETICA, 12f, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)));
    rcolSecLast1.BorderColor = Color.WHITE;
    table.AddCell(rcolSecLast1);


    PdfPCell rcolSecLast2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("--------------", new Font(Font.HELVETICA, 12f, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)));
    rcolSecLast2.BorderColor = Color.WHITE;
    table.AddCell(rcolSecLast2);

    PdfPCell rcolLast = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Total Offer  :", new Font(Font.HELVETICA, 12f, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)));

    rcolLast.BorderColor = Color.WHITE;
    table.AddCell(rcolLast);

    //table.AddCell("Total Offer  :");

    PdfPCell rcolLast1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(String.Format("{0:C}", boxTotal).ToString(), new Font(Font.HELVETICA, 12f, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)));

    rcolLast1.BorderColor = Color.WHITE;
    table.AddCell(rcolLast1);

    //table.AddCell(String.Format("{0:C}",boxTotal).ToString());
    return table;      
}
```

But, i am **Not able to Draw the Box with Orange Border and its contents using the `'PdfPTable'` and align to right as shown in fig.**. So, is their any other method to input HTML Markup in to the `PdfPTable`?

Please give the suggestions to do..!

Note: when user completes the PDF file is created and saved to a folder and not downloaded or view-able to user.

HTML Markup:

```
 <div style='width: 50%; border: 1px solid #000000; padding-bottom: 100px; padding-left: 100px;
        padding-right: 100px; text-align: justify; text-justify: inter-word;'>
        <br />
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="divLeft">
                        <p>
                            <img src='/images/Logo.png' width="200px" height="100px" /></p>
                        <h2>
                            Packing slip</h2>
                        <h3>
                            Place this slip inside the box with your device.</h3>
                        <div id="divDeviceList" style='width: 600px; text-align: left;' border="0" cellpadding="3"
                            cellspacing="1" rules="BOTH" frame="BOX">
                            <table style="width: 600px;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                       <strong> ITEM</strong>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                       <strong>  OFFER</strong>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        iPhone 5 32GB (AT&T)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        $205.00
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right">
                                    <hr />
                                     <strong><h3>Total Offer: &nbsp;</h3></strong>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                    <hr />
                                      <strong> <h3>  $215.00</h3></strong>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                            </table>


                        </div>

                            <h3>
                                You have until 01/29/2014 to ship your device.</h3>
                        <p style="padding:10px;">
                            <i>If you send your device after the expiration date we cannot honor your initial offer.
                                We will not accept devices that have been reported lost or stolen.</i></p>
                        <br />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="divRight">
                     <div style="text-align:right;padding:15px;"> <img src="../images/barcode.png" alt="barcode" /></div>
                        <table cellpadding="3" style="border: 1px solid orange;padding:20px;">

                        </tr>
                            <tr align="center">
                                <td>
                                   <img src="../images/pdfiphone.png" alt="iphone" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <h3>
                                        "Find my iPhone" must be turned off</h3>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    This feature locks your device and will delay or reduce payment.
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                 <strong>How to deactivate:</strong></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    1. Tap the “settings” icon on your homescreen.</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    2. Tap iCloud from the settings menu. </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    3. If “Find My iPhone” is on, tap the slider to turn it off.</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

**Can i use above HTML MARKUP and replace the string and create PDF and save to Folder with out viewing or Downloading by user?**